# Unexpected tokens in <!DOCTYPE html> in PyCharm Community Edition

Tags: python, django, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I am new in using PyCharm but I am loving it gradually. I am getting a red underline on `<!DOCTYPE html>` and the error is "Unexpected Token".

Why PyCharm shows it? I can't understand.

[image]

Comment: What does PyCharm report the error as? Hovering over the issue should revel the issue and potentially a solution.

Comment: I think there is no error...

Comment: Are you able to post the code raw? So that I may copy and paste this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It usually happens when you don't enable Django in Pycharm's settings. To resolve the problem:

1. In Pycharm open Setting in File menu
2. Select and expand Languages & Frameworks
3. Select Django and enable  it
4. Select your Django project root
5. Select your project setting.py file
6. Select your project manage.py file
7. Apply setting

Comment: for me looks like I need Pycharm Professional

Answer (score 5):

PyCharm does not provide support for the Django framework in the free community edition. The best solution may be to go with another IDE (at least until support is added).

Answer (score 1):

A simple and dirty solution is to use template semantic to prevent this false positive error. Here's an example for django 3.2.10:

Before:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

After:

```
{{ '<' }}{{ '!DOCTYPE html>' }}
```