# Django and Pycharm Community Edition Doctype html Unexpected Token

Tags: python, django

Good day! I am new to Python and currently following tutorials from youtube. I was following a tutorial wherein a downloaded dashboard would be deployed to django [(youtube video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=psvU4zwO3Ao&t=720s&ab_channel=PipInstallPython). Unfortunately, when trying to add the codes

```
{% load static %} 
{% load staticfiles %}
```

I am now prompted with an error `Unexpected Token` for the <!doctype HTML>

Is this a critical error? How can I solve this issue? I have seen this [Unexpected tokens in <!DOCTYPE html> in PyCharm Community Edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61277709/unexpected-tokens-in-doctype-html-in-pycharm-community-edition) topic but when I try to check the solution, I am not able to see the recommended answer. What should I do? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should try to remove `{% load staticfiles %}`

Comment: It is inside the template.The template on which the error has occurred